# Building compact subset of Vision model for MLKit

Tags: firebase, firebase-mlkit

Vision model in MLKit's Cloud API has all the labels I need. In fact I need only 100 of its 10000 labels. Can we retrain a compact version of that model to detect only 100 labels and deploy it on the android device so the app can run without internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

That's precisely what [Firebase ML Kit's image labeler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/label-images) does: it detects a subset of the labels that Cloud Vision detects by running a smaller ML model on-device.

If you want to control which labels it detects on the device, you'll have to train/[use a custom model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models).